# SocketTimeoutException

Tags: java, android

In my application I use a socket to communication with another device. All the time in I have a `SocketTimeoutException` . This communication I did in service

This is a logs :

```
11-09 08:44:05.029 5458-6647/pl.teminalmobile W/System.err: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
11-09 08:44:05.030 5458-6647/pl.teminalmobile W/System.err:     at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
11-09 08:44:05.031 5458-6647/pl.teminalmobile W/System.err:     at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:151)
11-09 08:44:05.031 5458-6647/pl.teminalmobile W/System.err:     at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:120)
11-09 08:44:05.031 5458-6647/pl.teminalmobile W/System.err:     at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:106)
11-09 08:44:05.032 5458-6647/pl.teminalmobile W/System.err:     at pl.teminalmobile.Service.Service22.start1(Service22.java:256)
11-09 08:44:05.032 5458-6647/pl.teminalmobile W/System.err:     at pl.teminalmobile.Service.Service22.access$000(Service22.java:75)
11-09 08:44:05.032 5458-6647/pl.teminalmobile W/System.err:     at pl.teminalmobile.Service.Service22$19.run(Service22.java:963)
11-09 08:44:05.033 5458-6647/pl.teminalmobile W/System.err:     at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
11-09 08:44:05.033 5458-6647/pl.teminalmobile W/System.err:     at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

this line couse a SocketTimeOutException :

```
  while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(content)) != -1) {
```

Comment: Why didnt you mention the line number?

Comment: `Service22.java:256)
11-09 08:44:05.032 5458-6647/pl.teminalmobile W/System.err:     at pl.teminalmobile.Service.Service22.access$000(Service22.java:75)
11-09 08:44:05.032 5458-6647/pl.teminalmobile W/System.err:     at pl.teminalmobile.Service.Service22$19.run(Service22.java:963)`. What is on those lines? They cause the time out isnt it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your socket is timing out means that it takes too long to get respond from other device and your request expires before getting response.To tackle this you need to give manual socket timeout like search for how to provide socket timeout of the library you are using. If using socket.io then you need to add

```
socket.timeout(12000);
```

Here 12000 are milli seconds or if you are using OkHttp Client then you can add:

```
clientBuilder.connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Or whichever socket library you are using there is method to give timeout manually so just type your socket name with which you created socket and place '.' after that you have suggestions for available methods in that search for timeout and use that method.

Here is the link use that library demo is also there:

https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java

Comment: If it works for you dont forget to mark this post as answer.Happy coding :)

Comment: I don't use a OkHttp Client  to send and get data I use a stream  , It is a good idea ? I set a timout requestSocket.setSoTimeout(7000); but it don't work corretly

Comment: for socket I suggest you to use socket.io library, I used it in several projects and its very good to go with. You dont have to face issues using socket.io well designed and optimized way to use sockets. So bro If its easy for you to switch to socket.io then go for it.

Comment: Could you show me which socket you recomended me? Which gradle depedencies I have to use

Comment: @KrzysztofPokrywka Bro I updated my answer and provided a link please follow that link, Instructions are also there you will good to go with that.I used it in many projects and it works like a charm.For further assistance do text me. And dont forget to mark post as answer if it helped you. Happy Coding :)

Comment: Could you show me how I can send a byte array and receiver a byte array ?

Comment: socket.on("message", new Emitter.Listener() {

        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
            byte[] bytearray = (byte[])args[0]; //received bytes

            for  (byte b : bytearray) {
                System.out.println("byte"+b);
            }
        }

    });

Comment: this is how you can send byte array

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem but I fix it by using these approaches

Set Character Encoding to UTF-8 and charset

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not entirely sure, I don't think you're using `Socket.setSoTimeout()` correctly. 
You're only supposed to use it once for the Socket requestSocket. Try having it at the beginning of your code before you work with the contents of the Socket, or make your code modular by passing it to a function instead of calling the function thrice. That makes it heaps easier to work with `Socket.setSoTimeout()` from my personal experience.

Answer (score 0):

I show you code you have pasted.

I found you set time 3000ms on line no 117 and 125 for timeout you need to change it maximum up to 15 second

```
requestSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(a, 6666), 3000);
```

Hope its help

Happy Coding.!