# Two HTTP get requests in the same activity resulting in a SocketTimeOutException

Tags: android, kotlin, http-get

In my main Activity i have two call with an httpget.

my two calls work individually but when ke puts both at the same time it's random.

Either it's the first that works well or the second and very rarely both at the same time.

```
    urlurg.httpGet().responseObject(ETATS.Deserializer())
    { request, response, result ->
       val(disurg,err) = result
       println("LISTE DES ETATS ...")
        disurg?.forEach { ETA ->
           println(ETA.desi)
           list.add(ETA.desi)
       }
       aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    url.httpGet().responseObject(DI.Deserializer())
    { request, response, result ->
        val (disw, err) = result
        println("LISTE DES DI : ......")
        disw?.forEach { DI ->
            dis.add(DI)
            println(DI.equipement)
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

do you have an idea of ​​why this behavior?

Thanks

Comment: What actually fails, what's the error? Could it be server-side?

Comment: yes i have "java.net.SocketTimeOutExeption : timeout" cause "socket closed"

Comment: I renamed the question to address the actual error. Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47196561/sockettimeoutexception. Also please post the stacktrace everytime you have an exception log